# How to create custom Authentication in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to create custom autentication scheme using pl/sql which for now just returns checks if username is "samman" or not.

```
FUNCTION authenticate(username IN VARCHAR2
                  ,password IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
BEGIN
    IF username='samman' THEN return true;
    ELSE return false;
    END IF;
END authenticate;
```

I am very new to apex and have no idea what most of the options do. So i have just written the above pl/sql code in "source" section and all the other setting are default.

When I run my application I get a ugly login page which looks like this.
[image]

So when i hit "samman" the authentication needs to be successful but "Invalid login credentials" error appears. This must be due to my lack of knowledge on how to set a new authentication schema. I found the resources online to be very lacking or vague when it comes to oracle apex. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you add "oracle apex" to all your searches, as there are quite a decent set of resources out there.

1. https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/custom-authentication-and-authorization-using-built-in-apex-access-control-a-how-to
2. https://www.lrayner.com/post/creating-a-custom-authentication-schema-apex-18-1
3. http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2017/08/create-custom-authentication-and.html

I'd suggest adding [apex.world](https://apex.world) to your list, if not already.

The authorisation scheme you're using, "open door credentials", is specifically for testing only, letting any any user with whatever username has been provided. A method to shortcut authentication that should **not** be used in production.

You want "custom"

Comment: Can you please tell me what i am or must be doing wrong in my implementation? It would be of great help. For now i just want i application to use above pl/sql logic to authenticate. Thank you.

Comment: Use "custom" authentication, as you initially described, instead of 'open door credentials', which you currently have selected. Then I suspect you may need to lower(username)